Use Python to automate excel to add in sub assemblies to list
I have a list of assemblies
WIP Products 
ABC123465
DEW7506
ASS7899

And a list that includes the sub assemblies
Master List
ABC123456
 .ABC124-21
BCC45645
DEW7506
 .DEW50564-002-M45
CCC45613
 .CCC456456
 .. CCC12315
ASS7899
 .ASS4564
 ..AS564-1546
 ...AS54616

The master list has everything and the WIP Product list only has top level numbers that are being produced.  What I am trying to create is a third list that has everything from the WIP Product with the associated sub assemblies (indicated by "." in front of the number.   The # of dots indicates the BOM level.   I do have a column in my spreadsheet on Master Sheet tab that indicates the top level as a 0 and the other levels as 1, 2, etc.
I am trying to figure out how to use Python either with or without Pandas to be able to automate this.
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

fileName = "Production capacity and order tracking.xlsx"

"""mdsSchedule = pd.read_excel(fileName,sheet_name="MDS Schedule Tracking",
                            header=0, usecols="A,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L")
"""
mdsScheduleAssembly = pd.read_excel(fileName,sheet_name="MDS Schedule Tracking",
                            header=0, usecols="A")

subs = pd.read_excel(fileName,sheet_name="Mfg Lead w-subs",
                            header=1, usecols="A,D")

wipAssemblies = []

for row in mdsScheduleAssembly
     
    for row in subs
       
        if 


The exact code depends on how your data is structured in the excel. But at a high level, you could solve this by:
Step 1) going through and making a dictionary from the master list where every key is a product and the associated entry is a tuple containing all of the sub-assemblies associated with that product.
Step 2) iterating through the WIP list, getting each associated key, and appending it to your output in your chosen format.
